# Position div tag at the bottom right of an image

Tags: html, css, position

I am trying to position an div element at the bottom right of an image, that is inside a container element. I set position relative to the container, and position absolute to the inner div, but it does not work. Here is the (http://jsfiddle.net/ZC84G/). Please, help.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="icon"></div>
   <img src="/images/someImage.png" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: black;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
}
.container img {
    max-width: 75%;
    max-height: 80%;
}

.icon{
    background-image: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconfactory/star-wars-lego/32/Biggs-No-Helmet-icon.png');
    width: 31px;
    height: 31px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: no your design should have a rule concerning the max image size, you should write your CSSs according to that. To set it dynamically wouldn't help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because by default div has **block** display mode, and it's width is 100% of the parent container. Try to add **display: inline** to **.container**

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
}
```

Here's the corrected jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZC84G/4/

Answer (score 0):

Your container `div` has no `width` and `height` set. And since a `<div>` is a `block-level` element by default, it will be set to `100%` width ie expand to however much horizontal space is left.

Plus, you're also constraining your image size:

```
max-width: 75%;
max-height: 80%;
```

If you replace the img **CSS** with:

```
max-width: 75%;
max-height: 80%;
```

It works fine, and as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/ZC84G/3/

Comment: thank you, but I am not sure I could remove the percentage constraint

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your CSS on the image a bit.

Basically, I set it to scale properly to the size of its container, and now it sits where I think you wanted it. The way you could find this yourself in the future would be to inspect the element by using right click from your browser, and looking at the size of the different elements to see what was expanding larger/smaller than it should.

```
.container img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: believe me the web inspector is always open, the image percent constraint was mandatory.